# Risk of enabling CORS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

Amazon S3 provides a way to enable CORS support on a per-bucket basis. By default, though, CORS is disabled.

I can't think of a single security risk involved with enabling wildcard CORS for my S3 buckets, but presumably there must be at least some danger, or else they'd have just enabled it for everything and wouldn't provide such elaborate rules for exactly which domains to trust.

Can someone describe an exploit or other reason why I wouldn't want to just set `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>` on all of my buckets?

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing):

> `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
>
> This is generally not appropriate. The only case where this is
>   appropriate is when a page or API response is considered completely
>   public content and it is intended to be accessible to everyone,
>   including any code on any site.

Here is an example where you would need to use CORS but you should avoid using the wildcard: you store content on S3 that you need to access from your app (hosted on another URL) using AJAX, but you don't want to make that content publicly available to other sites (e.g. a HTML or JSON file that stores some of your app's data, where those files should not be available from other sites).

There are also other scenarios like the possibility to upload content to your S3 bucket, from other sites by using AJAX.

Comment: But for this to be a risk, the data must be publicly accessible, and if the risk is that somebody else will host the data and I'll be charged for that, S3 already offers the "aws:Referer" method of blocking other domains.

Comment: Yes, the data would need to be publicly available. If none of your data is public (it always requires authentication) then the CORS wildcard is not really an issue. If someone can upload data in your bucket they might do more damage than just generating additional charges, depending on how your app works (e.g. XSS attacks). Using "aws:Referer" to restrict access will not offer you 100% protection in all cases, but on the other hand neither does Access-Control-Allow-Origin as its just one additional layer of protection.